# STM32F3Discovery programming with openocd

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, openocd, stm32f4

first of all I'm sorry for my really poor English.
I'm learning how to use an STM32F3Discovery board.
I wrote a simple program that turn-on all the on-board led, using STMCubeMX for configuration-code generation. 
The code i've written is just the following eight line.

```
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

There is a copy of the Eclipse project [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bryn7x73ftlv45g/blink.zip?dl=0).
I'm trying to program the board using openocd, so I run

```
openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32f3discovery.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink-v2.cfg
```

then

```
​telnet localhost 4444 
​reset halt
flash write_image erase blink.elf
​reset
```

The output of openocd is

```
Open On-Chip Debugger
> reset halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x2b061a1a msp: 0x48054b04
> flash write_image erase blink.elf
auto erase enabled
couldn't open blink.elf
in procedure 'flash'
> flash write_image erase blink.elf
auto erase enabled
device id = 0x10036422
flash size = 256kbytes
target state: halted
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000003a msp: 0x48054b04
wrote 2048 bytes from file blink.elf in 0.224231s (8.919 KiB/s)
> reset
```

But none of the led is turned on!
What should I do?

Comment: 2048 bytes looks like a bit short even for such a simple program, when the HAL libraries are involved

Comment: The target state is halted yes? Try 'reset run' on the telnet prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The `couldn't open blink.elf` message indicates that the file `blink.elf` might not be in the current directory.

Make sure to execute the openocd command from the folder that contains the `blink.elf` firmware image you intend to program.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. If you're using Windows, the solution is to open Terminal with administrator privileges. If you're using Linux, you might need to use sudo.